# The Jumping Facebook Like button bug on IE 7, how can it be fixed?

Tags: css, facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is this is known bug and is there a workaround?  The Facebook Like button will jump forever in IE 7.  Take a look at

http://jsfiddle.net/Z53cs/10

using IE 7.  And if you use IE 8 (and probably IE 9 as well which I don't have at work), you can use "Developer Tools" and change to "Browser Mode: IE 7"
and you will see the Jumping Facebook Like Button.

The code is very simple:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>

hello world <fb:like href="www.google.com" layout="button_count" 
               show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>
```

The `font-size` is to show that jumping of the button.  If `font-size` is removed, as in http://jsfiddle.net/Z53cs/11 then the text of "hello world" jump instead, caused by the
styling change of the Facebook Like Button.  Also, due to this, if you look at the CPU graph using the Task Manager on Windows, you will see the CPU going up to 100%, and down, every 2 seconds or so. (I am using VirtualBox 4.0.4 on a Macbook Pro (2 years old), emulating 2 processors running XP, and IE 8 using IE 7 Compatibility mode)

Has anyone seen this and know why the jumping?  And any workaround or fix?

---

**Update**: if I use Fiddler to view the net traffic, it seems like it is roloading the page every second on the clock, so if you
are viewing the page on jsfiddle.net, it will refresh from fiddle.jshell.net, and if you put the HTML code in your webpage on www.foo.com, you will see the page refreshing every second fetching www.foo.com/?fb_xd_fragment

**Update**: running this in Windows 7's Virtual PC, emulating a machine with 1GB of RAM, the VPC will start up having about 820MB free (unused), and our page loads up, will be about 775MB free, and then every second, a few MB is eaten away, until Windows XP on the VPC needs to increase virtual memory by increasing the page file, and IE 7 stops responding at last.

Comment: Reproduced here, how strange. No idea how to fix it, but it looks like Facebook is *doing it wrong* for IE7.

Comment: only jumps once in ie tester eith ie7... also tried ie8 in compatability mode and again, only jumped once...

Comment: @Damien do you see a popdown bar (under the URL) saying:  it tries to download and either to OK it or not. (probably for the page refresh)

Comment: yeah it didnt download properly first time... i hit refresh and its now jumping nonstop... i had a go at fixing it, but no luck sorry :(

Comment: There is a bug logged on Facebook which is covering issues with the FBML Like button in IE and I think this is related: [Bug 16512](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=16512) - XFBML Like button jiggles and causes rerequests to FB.
Hope this helps you. As for me I'm going with a more basic, AddThis implementation that doesn't have the pop-up comments box and wait until the code has stabilised before implementing on my site.

Comment: Actuall, I think that I may have just confused things, I think that Facebook Bug 9777 is for something else, sorry for any confusion.  I still have the problem too and have just resigned myself to implementing a simpler Like button for now using AddThis.

Comment: last time I tried, the "standard" layout that says, "Be the first of your friends"... instead of the `box_count` type works ok on IE 7... so maybe if the server code detected it is IE7, use that instead... somewhat ugly way... and need to style it to hide the phrase if that's too long...  until the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that I found a workaround:

add float css attribute:

```
<fb:like href="URL" layout="button_count" show_faces="true" width="150" style='float: left;' font="arial"></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding the facebook script inside a div and give it `overflow: hidden`.

For example

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
     <div id="fb-root"></div>
     <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.jsxxxxxxxxxx;xfbml=1"></script>        
     <fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/xxxxxxxxx/62625" send="false" layout="button_count" width="95" show_faces="false" font="" style="float:left; width:50px;"></fb:like>
</div>
```